# Laravel 5 UnsupportedLocaleException in LaravelLocalization.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.1 and I would like to use the following package:
https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

I added this code to my route.php file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()], function()
    {
       /** ADD ALL LOCALIZED ROUTES INSIDE THIS GROUP **/
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return View::make('hello');
    });

    Route::get('test',function(){
        return View::make('test');
    });
});
```

When calling the url: localhost/test I get the following exception:
UnsupportedLocaleException in LaravelLocalization.php line 119: Laravel default locale is not in the supportedLocales array

Any ideas why? Thank you

Comment: Have you added in a `use` statement for the whole path OR alias?

Comment: Have you changed the `app.locale` for default locale?

Comment: Did you add the default locale of your Laravel installation to the [config of the package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/blob/master/src/config/config.php) respectively uncomment it? Looks like you have to do that...

Comment: Yes, I forgot to set the default locale in my Laravel installation. Thank you. When I need addtional languages except the default 'en' or 'es' it is a good idea to uncomment the necessary languages in the config.php of the vendors directory (vendor/mcamara/laravel-localization..) or should/can the languages be added in the config/app.php file in an array?

Answer (score 6):

NEXTLEVELSHIT is right, but another option is to override the config file by publishing the config file:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalizationServiceProvider"
```

That way you can go to config/laravellocalization.php and uncommend the languagues you need to use.

Answer (score 5):

## Reason

Inside your `config/app.php` you've set somthing like this:

```
...

'locale' => 'de',

...
```

If you have not uncommented exactliy this language in `vendor/mcamara/laraval-localization/src/config/config.php`, you will get this certain error.

## Solution

Go to `vendor/mcamara/laraval-localization/src/config/config.php` and uncomment:

```
...

//'se'          => ['name' => 'Northern Sami',          'script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'davvisámegiella'],
  'de'          => ['name' => 'German',                 'script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'Deutsch'],
//'luo'         => ['name' => 'Luo',                    'script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'Dholuo'],

...
```

## Background

If you are developing your app locally and deploying on a external server, your `vendor` folder in general won't be pulled from your repository. Usually you omit `/vendor` inside `.gitignore` from being tracked.